# Communication between a Django Web App and an external Server running python scripts

Tags: django, server, connection, execution

I am currently working on a web page using Django. This website aims at displaying results of different simulations. I can not use the code of some simulation directly in my Django backend. But the code owners allow me to do a black box simulation using their own servers. So the idea is to first send some sort of request with data to the server. The data was inputed earlier by the user and saved in the django database. Then the server receives the data and excecutes a simulation (a python script) using this data. After the simulation is finished the data is sent back to my django backend, so my django backend receives some kind of response.
I researched a lot on this topic but could not really find something I could use. I saw stuff like python sockets, socket.io, websockets, django rest framework and django channels, but I did not really see how I could apply one of these libraries to my case. How do I achieve what a described earlier? How can I connect my django project to a remote server (in a different city)? Where do I start?

[figure showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMKF6.png)

I tried to implement a server and client using python sockets but this had no connection to django. I looked into Django channels but did not see how I could connect to a remote server instead of many clients.

I tried to find a way to setup a server (in a terminal) and then implement a communication between this server and my backend in django simulating this scenario of the communication to an external server, but I could not find a method to do so yet.

And if this generally seems like a bad practice, I am open for suggestions on how to incooperate simulations in my website without direct access to the simulation code.

Comment: Where are those servers located? Something is not adding up, the simulation is executed on their servers? You said the data is being sent back to your database, which I assume is going to be hosted on some server or in the cloud. How it will be sent or this what you are asking us, how to be sent and how to receive it? This simulation must happen in real time? A bpmn diagram would have helped a lot.

Comment: Yeah the simulation would be executed in real time. And I am asking how the communication between my website and a external server would work. What framework or library I have to use, considering that my website runs on django? And how would this be implemented? I understand that there will be some code on my side establishing a connection with the server and then sending or receiving data via this connection. Also there will be code on the external server side doing the same thing. But how excatly it is done I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you need and here's how I'd do it. First, the simulation server needs to publish the simulation result in a widely accepted format, preferably JSON to an eventbus. Next, your django app will listen to the events from the bus and creates the records in the db if they need to be persistent, else just store them in cache, using redis. From there, push the simulations via websockets to the frontend client and render them. I'm attaching a small diagram on how the process would look like. All this stack can be quite overwhelming to be developed and maintained by a single developer without any DevOPs support, so it would useful and cheap to use some of AWS managed services for both the bus and websockets.

[image]

If the whole project is about this, django is not even required, you can go with a serveless approach using [chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice). A lambda function (written in python) triggered whenever a new event has been published to the bus, can save the records to dynamodb and also publish to the aws websockets and if you need to access later or upon refresh the same simulations you can develop another lambda as REST API on top of the dynamodb.

[image]

Instead of the dynamoDB you can use any db, but in your case this is the easiest to work with and readily available.

Reasons why to use an eventbus in between:

- the events can be consumed multiple times, so even if fails to save once, the data can be fetched again and process restarted
- low coupling, you are not tied to http network errors, server load, etc.